# Reverse Reverse Insertion Sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

given an array
A = [5,4,3,2,6]

use insertion sorting algorithm but starting at the last index... sort ascending order (python)

ex: Iteration 1

A=[5,4,3,2,6]

ex: iteration 2

A =[5,4,2,3,6]

and so on until

A= [2,3,4,5,6]

really stuck on this one ...

```
  for j in range(len(arr), j>0):
    value_to_sort = arr[j]
    while arr[j-1] > value_to_sort and j>0:
      arr[j], arr[j-1] = arr[j-1], arr[j]
      i = i+1
  return arr
```

is what i have so far any help or guidance would be appriciated

Comment: In your snippet you use some very strange syntax - `range(len(arr), j>0)`.  The rest does not make much sense either.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

- The second value you pass to `range` should be an index value, not a condition, and as you want to count down, you need to use the third argument as well. So `range(len(arr), -1, -1)`
- The inner loop uses a name that has not been defined: `i`. It should be defined, *and* actually used in the array indexing.
- The value to sort should be compared with values that are at its *right* (the already sorted partition), so `arr[j-1]` is not a good value to compare it with.
- `j > 0` in the inner loop condition is not helpful, since the inner loop does not change `j`
- Instead of swapping, it is better to only *find* the right spot to insert the value to sort, and then perform the move *after* that loop has found it.

Corrected code:

```
def inssort(arr):
  for j in range(len(arr) - 1, -1, -1):
    value_to_sort = arr[j]
    for i in range(j + 1, len(arr)):
      if arr[i] > value_to_sort:
         break
    else:
      i = len(arr)
    # rotate the value_to_sort in its right position
    arr[j:i-1] = arr[j+1:i]
    arr[i-1] = value_to_sort
  return arr
```